# removing memory leaks in c++ and GNU scientific library code

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, gsl, memory-management

```
double a[] = { 0.11, 0.12, 0.13,
                  0.21, 0.22, 0.23 };

   double b[] = { 1011, 1012,
                  1021, 1022,
                  1031, 1032 };

   double c[] = { 0.00, 0.00,
                  0.00, 0.00 };

   gsl_matrix_view A = gsl_matrix_view_array(a, 2, 3);
   gsl_matrix_view B = gsl_matrix_view_array(b, 3, 2);
   gsl_matrix_view C = gsl_matrix_view_array(c, 2, 2);

   /* Compute C = A B */

   gsl_blas_dgemm (CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans,
                   1.0, &A.matrix, &B.matrix,
                   0.0, &C.matrix);
```

how do I deallocate the memory assigned to the matrices?

Comment: Where did you allocate memory that you want to deallocate? Your code snippet shows no allocation.

Comment: If GSL allocates memory for matrix calculations, it shall release memory, when no longer needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will take care of those matrices. Unless you use `malloc()/new[]` or any function that uses `malloc()/new[]` and gives you ownership of the allocated memory there're no chances to leak memory.

If you asked about [gsl_matrix_view_array()](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Matrix-views.html) - the documentation says that the return value is a pointer to a view in the original matrix which means that no extra matrix is allocated - you only get a pointer into the same matrix. So unless you used `malloc()/new` to allocate the original matrix you shouldn't do anything. If you use `malloc()/new[]` for the original matrix (not your case, but anyway) - call `free()/delete[]` on the original matrix, not on a view.

Comment: Erm, and `new`, Shirley? (This having a `c++` tag.)

Comment: @sbi: I looked at the code and thought the library had a C interface, so I didn't think of C++. Fixed.

Comment: Yeah, the question probably should have a `c` tag instead of `c++`. But since it has the `c++` tag...